# Reading material for Kähler geometry

Tags: reference-request, symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I'd like to read and understand [this paper](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~kamenova/homepage_files/special-kahler.pdf) on Kähler geometry. The most advanced math I've done is a read through Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis which teaches analysis up to differential forms and basic Lebesgue theory. What book(s) should I read now so that I have the proper background to understand this paper?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you add `reference-request` to your tags.

Comment: I don't know how much differential geometry you know, but let's start with something like R.O.Wells *Differential analysis on complex manifolds*.

Comment: Thank you!! I added the tag and I'll definitely check out that book

Answer (score 1):

Gauchon's book: [https://cims.nyu.edu/~rodion/lib/P.%20Gauduchon.%20Calabi%27s%20extremal%20Kähler%20metrics:%20An%20elementary%20introduction%20-%202017.pdf](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Erodion/lib/P.%20Gauduchon.%20Calabi%27s%20extremal%20K%C3%A4hler%20metrics:%20An%20elementary%20introduction%20-%202017.pdf)

Griffiths and Harris -- Principles of Algebraic Geometry

Huybrechts -- Complex Geometry

Tian -- Canonical metrics in Kähler geometry.

Gabor Szekelyhidi's book --  An Introduction to Extremal Kahler Metrics

Moroianu's Lectures on Kähler geometry.

Werner Ballman's book.